# Attempting to loop the following

Tags: bash, list

I've been using a simple script to extract information from my .nessus files.

```
cat blee.nessus | grep -o 'severity="4.*"' | sort --unique | wc -l && cat blee.nessus | grep -o 'severity="3.*"' | sort --unique | wc -l && cat blee.nessus | grep -o 'severity="2.*"' | sort --unique | wc -l && cat blee.nessus | grep -o 'severity="1.*"' | sort --unique | wc -l && cat blee.nessus | grep cvss_base | tr -d '<cvss_base_score>'| tr -d '/' | paste -sd+ | bc
```

It outputs this:

```
2
0
13
4
2237.7
```

I have a directory full of .nessus files.  Is there a way to iterate the commands above onto all the .nessus files and ID which files are being output ie:

```
blee.nessus
2
0
13
4
2237.7
```

I've tried to do something with find . -iname "*.nessus" to execute these commands but can't seem to get the syntax correctly.

Thanks for your help on this,

Comment: `tr -d` doesn't delete a string, it deletes *any character in that string*, no matter where it is or what order it's in.

Comment: So `tr -d '<cvss_base_score>'` will delete any `c`, any `v`, any `_`, etc. from anywhere in your input.

Comment: ...frankly, if you're parsing through an XML document, you'll be much, *much* better off (in terms of reliability and robustness) using XML-aware tools from the shell -- see in particular [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/).

Comment: (Also, as a relatively minor point -- `cat foo | bar` is much more efficiently written as `<foo bar` or `bar <foo`; that way `bar` has a handle directly on the file, not on a FIFO to a separate program that's spun up to do just the read. This is a huge enough pipeline with enough other inefficiencies that that won't make a difference, but there are other cases where it matters quite a lot -- for instance, if you're calling `sort`, a good implementation can parallelize when given a real file handle, but has to read front-to-back given a FIFO).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just a `for` loop?

```
for i in *.nessus; do
    echo "$i"
    cat "$i" | ... rest of your command ...
done
```